# How to perform click/tap operation to the perticular bound/co-ordinates in python script for Android UI using appium

Tags: android, python, selenium, appium

I am writing testcases in python script for android application using appium. I want to perform click/tap operation in a particular bounds/co-ordinates. but I am not able to perform it.Can any one tell me how to do it.

class firstTest(unittest.TestCase):

```
def tearDown(self):
    "Tear down the test"
    self.driver.quit()

def test_single_player_mode(self):
    time.sleep(5)
    element = self.driver.find_element_by_name("Enter your Email ID or User name")
    element.send_keys("username")
    element = self.driver.find_element_by_name("Let's get started!")
    element.click()
    time.sleep(5)
```

Till 'Lets get started it is working fine. After it in UI, I don't have any element name or id. I have only particular bound to click the element. I want to click on bound [918,154][1086,324] resource ID for above bound is "com.abc.android.cap:id/friends_selection_list" Please tell me how to do after it.

Comment: Did you get solution?

Comment: No, i didn't get any solution

Comment: I have one more question, can you suggest for it. Please check on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27898661/how-to-enter-numeric-values-using-mobile-keypad-in-android-app-in-python-script/29017158#29017158

Comment: check my comment there...

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have `content-description` for this element. In that case you can tap on it by using it and `tap` method in `TouchAction` class.

```
ele = self.driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id('content-description of your element')
action = TouchAction(self.driver)
action.tap(ele).perform()
```

Comment: surya,where i want to perform click/tap operation on that view there are 5 button that have same description id. i have only the co-ordinates/bounds for each button. So pls tell me how to perform tap/click on particular co-ordinates/bounds

Comment: Okay. In that case use the method that finds multiple elements & then get the required button from that list to click on it. That is, you need to use ""self.driver.find_elements_by_accessibility_id". I would suggest, use co-ordination based approach only if none of the other option is working.

Comment: yes, surya i have tried all the options. so i think the only option is only by co-ordinates

Comment: And it doesn't have content description id. So i have only last option and that is co-ordinates

Answer (score 0):

U can use Xpath of that element, for finding xpath u will need appium inspector, which is supported in MAC OSX only, so you have to use an mac and configure Android SDK and Appium on MAC in order to get it working.
Code will be like this :

```
 #-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
__author__ = 'chetan.krishna'
import os
import time
import unittest
from time import sleep
from appium import webdriver
from pylab import *
from teamcity import is_running_under_teamcity
from teamcity.unittestpy import TeamcityTestRunner
import logging

# Returns absolute path relative to this file
PATH = lambda p: os.path.abspath(
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), p)
)


class AvavntiAndroidTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        desired_caps = {}
# Specify platform below(Android, iOS)
        desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
# Specify OS version(Settings->About phone -> android version)
        desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '4.4.4'
# Obtain the Device name from Adb[For Android](Terminal Command: "adb devices")
        desired_caps['deviceName'] = '4d0081004c8741a9'

        desired_caps['noReset'] = False
# Specify the path to Application
        desired_caps["app"] = PATH('AvantiMarket_v1.4.apk')
# Wait for email login activity to appear
        desired_caps["appWaitActivity"]= ('com.android.avantimarket.ui.activity.EmailLoginActivity')
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)

    def tearDown(self):
# end the session
        self.driver.quit()


    def test_Avanti(self):
# wait for the login screen to appear
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(20)
# set values for plotting pass and fail results
        nPass = 0
        nFail = 0
        print('Checking login for registered user')
    # Logging in as indiaone@avantilab.org
elf.driver.implicitly_wait('20')
        print('Trying to login with abc@abc.org')
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[2]/UIATextField[1]').send_keys('abc@abc.org.org')
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[2]/UIASecureTextField[1]').send_keys('12345678')
        self.driver.hide_keyboard()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[2]/UIAButton[3]').click()
        time.sleep(20)
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(99)
        try:
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[2]/UIASecureTextField[1]')
        except :
            print('Login failed, please check credentials and network')
        else:
            print('Login successful, creating pin')

        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[2]/UIASecureTextField[1]').send_keys('1')
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[2]/UIASecureTextField[2]').send_keys('1')
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[2]/UIASecureTextField[3]').send_keys('1')
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[2]/UIASecureTextField[4]').send_keys('1')
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[2]/UIASecureTextField[5]').send_keys('1')
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('com.android.avantimarket:id/m_emailTextField').send_keys('abc@abc.org.org')
        self.driver.back()
        nPass= nPass+1
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(20)
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('com.android.avantimarket:id/m_passwordTextField').send_keys('12345678')
        nPass= nPass+1
        self.driver.back()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        self.driver.find_element_by_name('SIGN IN').click()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        time.sleep(5)
# validating for successful login
        try:
            self.driver.find_element_by_id('com.android.avantimarket:id/create_pin_fields_container')
            print('Login successful')
            nPass= nPass+1
        except:
            print('Login failed')
            nFail = nFail + 1
        else:
# Creating pin required for login
            print('Creating Pin for user')
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('com.android.avantimarket:id/create_pin_fields_container').send_keys('1111')
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('com.android.avantimarket:id/reEnter_pin_fields_container').send_keys('1111')
        self.driver.back()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(20)
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('com.android.avantimarket:id/m_saveButton').click()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('com.android.avantimarket:id/btn_cominsoon_Yes').click()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        time.sleep(8)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with [Touch Actions](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/touch-actions.md).

```
action = TouchAction(self.driver)
action.tap(element=None, x=100, y=600, count=2).perform()
```

Or like this:

```
self.driver.tap([(100,600)], 500)
```

Where the first variable is a list of up to 5 x,y coordinates(e.g. `self.driver.tap([(495,757), (200,500)], 500)`. The last number is duration of the tap.