# How to enter numeric values using mobile keypad in android app in python script using Appium

Tags: android, python, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am writing a python script to automate android application. 
I want to enter values in text board using mobile `keypad`.

I was able to enter the value in text field using `send_keys`, but in some cases I have to enter values using android keypad i.e `digits(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0)` etc.

Can anyone tell me how to enter these value using keypad?

Comment: Do you not able to write digits using "sendkeys" method?

Comment: Yes, i am able to use send_keys. But its just paste the data in textbox. I want to type each digit from mobile keypad. Please help.

Comment: Please check, My be something can help you here : http://www.ontestautomation.com/up-and-running-with-selendroid/

Comment: Same issue, still not able to type though keypad.Can u please suggest anything else?

Comment: Do you using real device? Also what exact error you are getting when going to type..

Comment: yes i am using real device. i am getting some error related to Assert not defined.  it doesn't have any its because i am writing the script in python and appium as server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73249/discussion-between-harry-and-helping-hands).

Answer (score 0):

try this
        emailSign = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("UIATextField")
        passSign = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("UIASecureTextField")

```
    passSign.click()

    emailSign.send_keys(username + carriage_return)
    passSign.send_keys(password + carriage_return)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do here, but you can send keystrokes with selenium:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common import keys
textfield.send_keys(keys.Keys().ENTER)
```

Where 'textfield' is your text field element. If you look at the Keys class in selenium, you can send any of the keyboard keys. This is useful if you want to hide the keyboard - just send a tab key and it will focus elsewhere.

Comment: I want to enter values in text board using mobile keypad.I was able to enter the value in text field using send_keys. But in some cases i have to enter values using android keypad i.e digits(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0) etc. Can you tell me how to enter these value using keypad.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Python, but this is how I overcome a similar issue from a **Java** client code.

```
AndroidDriver driver;
//... then setup driver

//... put some text on target text field
textfield.click();
textfield.sendKeys("some content");

//... finally send Enter key
driver.sendKeyEvent(AndroidKeyCode.ENTER);
```

Check if the Python API offers such enumeration.
Hope this helps.